# List of well known VSS Writer GUIDs

Tags: guid, volume-shadow-service

Is there a consolidated list of GUIDs for well known VSS writers available somewhere? At least the Microsoft ones like System State, Exchange, SQL, Sharepoint etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well now there is one started here :-)

```
/** Microsot Exchange Writer. */
public static final String EXCHANGE_GUID = $("76FE1AC4-15F7-4BCD-987E-8E1ACB462FB7");

/** MSDE Writer for SQL server 2000 and before. Still works under SQL SVR 2005 but preferred is #SQL_SERVER_GUID */
public static final String SQL_SERVER_2000_GUID = $("F8544AC1-0611-4FA5-B04B-F7EE00B03277");

/** Sql Server Writer */
public static final String SQL_SERVER_GUID = $("A65FAA63-5EA8-4EBC-9DBD-A0C4DB26912A");

/** Service State Writer */
public static final String MS_SERVICE_STATE = $("E38C2E3C-D4FB-4F4D-9550-FCAFDA8AAE9A");

/** Bootable State writer */
public static final String MS_BOOTABLE_STATE = $("F2436E37-09F5-41AF-9B2A-4CA2435DBFD5");

/** Automated System Recovery (ASR) Writer */
public static final String ASR_WRITER = $("BE000CBE-11FE-4426-9C58-531AA6355FC4"); // vista en 2008

/** Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) Writer */
public static final String BITS_WRITER = $("4969D978-BE47-48B0-B100-F328F07AC1E0");

/** Event Log Writer */
public static final String EVT_WRITER = $("EEE8C692-67ED-4250-8D86-390603070D00");

/** System Writer */
public static final String SYS_WRITER = $("E8132975-6F93-4464-A53E-1050253AE220");

/** Registry Writer */
public static final String REG_WRITER = $("AFBAB4A2-367D-4D15-A586-71DBB18F8485");

/** COM+ Class Registration Database Writer */
public static final String COMREG_WRITER = $("542DA469-D3E1-473C-9F4F-7847F01FC64F");

/** Active Directory Domain Services (NTDS) VSS Writer */
public static final String NTDS_WRITER = $("B2014C9E-8711-4C5C-A5A9-3CF384484757");

/** File Replication Service Writer */
public static final String FRS_WRITER = $("D76F5A28-3092-4589-BA48-2958FB88CE29");

/** WMI Writer */
public static final String WMI_WRITER = $("A6AD56C2-B509-4E6C-BB19-49D8F43532F0");

/** IIS Metabase Writer */
public static final String IISMETA_WRITER = $("59B1f0CF-90EF-465F-9609-6CA8B2938366");

/** Shadow Copy Optimization Writer */
public static final String OPT_WRITER = $("4DC3BDD4-AB48-4D07-ADB0-3BEE2926FD7F");//vss optimization writer

/** IIS Configuration Writer */
public static final String IISCONFIG_WRITER = $("2A40FD15-DFCA-4aa8-A654-1F8C654603F6"); 

/** Microsoft Hyper-V VSS Writer */
public static final String HYPERV_WRITER = $("66841CD4-6DED-4F4B-8F17-FD23F8DDC3DE"); 

/** File Server Resource Manager (FSRM) Writer */
public static final String FSRM_WRITER = $("12CE4370-5BB7-4C58-A76A-E5D5097E3674");

/** 
 * Performance Counters Writer - From Win7 and 2008 R2 onwards.
 */
public static final String PERFORMANCE_COUNTERS_WRITER = $("0BADA1DE-01A9-4625-8278-69E735F39DD2");    

/** Task Scheduler Writer - From Win7 and 2008 R2 onwards */
public static final String TASK_SCHEDULER_WRITER = $("D61D61C8-D73A-4EEE-8CDD-F6F9786B7124");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `VSSADMIN LIST WRITERS` on your command line?

Comment: Yes thanks, but that only gives me writers on my local system. I want to cater for systems that is not installed

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a definitive list anywhere. Best I could suggest would be to google using existing GUIDs you've found on your system, e.g. googling for "a65faa63-5ea8-4ebc-9dbd-a0c4db26912a" (the SQLServerWriter), finds forums posts for people seeking help, and tend to include their own writer lists. From there, you could compile a fairly good list.